# Sync logitech keyboard and mouse connection when I switch devices

Tags: keyboard, mouse, bluetooth, logitech-mouse, logitech-keyboard

I recently bought Logitech MK850 keyboard and mouse combo which has M720 Triathlon mouse and K850 performance wireless keyboard.

So far, I love the features and the ability to switch bluetooth connection device is just great. I frequently work between my personal laptop and my office laptop and switching between them instantly is awesome.

My only issue is that sometimes I switch my mouse to device 2 and forget switching my keyboard to device 2 only to realize I forgot to switch and have entered keystrokes into the wrong device. Is there a way to sync it up? ie if I switch my mouse to device 2 then the keyboard would automatically do the same and vice versa

Comment: Going to be blunt — No, I don't think this can be done.

Answer (score 1):

I too very much want this.  Although it is good that Logitech acknowledged this is a highly desired feature, unfortunately, they said it is not easy to implement and no guarantees.  The recommended Logitech FLOW as a partial workaround.  Details:

- "We do understand that this is a feature that a lot of customers would like."
- "It is not possible to use one Easy-Switch button to at the same time change both your mouse and keyboard to a different computer/device...we cannot guarantee this solution at the moment, as it is not easy to implement."
- https://support.logi.com/hc/en-us/articles/1500008089162-Can-I-switch-my-mouse-and-keyboard-at-the-same-time-using-one-Easy-Switch-button-
- (I did not see a date on the above Logitech answer/FAQ)

Comment: Your answer is unclear.